# Significance Value on Design of Experiments Analysis

Tags: t-test, experiment-design

I'm doing a DOE style analysis on a small amount of data that is two-factor with two levels. I've followed steps I've learnt from the ASQ and got a graph and values for the effect of my two variables and the combination.

During a meeting with another company I saw that they had done a similar analysis, but had standardized their data somehow so that they could compare the effect values from the DOE analysis with the p-value for 0.05 significance and were able to make a statement on which variables were significant in the outcome they were measuring.

As I understand it the p-value will be obtained from completing a t-test but I am unsure how I can standardize my effect values to compare to this (the 0.05 p-value significance would just be read of a table?).

Is there a way to do this and is it a common method in DOE analysis? I am learning it from scratch from online resources and am fairly new to statistics so appreciate I msay be missing something simple.